# Name not found exception when updating to latest casting library version

Tags: android, chromecast, android-cast-api

So I'm trying to update the chrome cast library (from 1.x to 2.x) in my app and casting is working but when I try to add this to my manifest to enable notifications I get a package name not found exception. The reason I've targeted this as the problem is that I can cast perfectly when I remove this from my manifest. I also wanted to add that I got this manifest declaration from the example [here](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml).

```
 <receiver android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.remotecontrol.VideoIntentReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" />
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
      <action android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.action.toggleplayback" />
      <action android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.action.stop" />
      <action android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.action.rewind" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

  <service
      android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService"
      android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.action.notificationvisibility" />
    </intent-filter>
  </service>

  <service android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.reconnection.ReconnectionService"/>
```

Here's the full error.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{my.package.name/com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.player.VideoCastControllerActivity}
 at android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack(TaskStackBuilder.java:247)
 at android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack(TaskStackBuilder.java:226)
 at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService.getContentIntent(VideoCastNotificationService.java:492)
 at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService.build(VideoCastNotificationService.java:329)
 at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService$2.onPostExecute(VideoCastNotificationService.java:233)
 at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService$2.onPostExecute(VideoCastNotificationService.java:227)
 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
 at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
 Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{my.package.name/com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.player.VideoCastControllerActivity}
 at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:314)
 at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.getParentActivityName(NavUtils.java:301)
 at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(NavUtils.java:256)
 at android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack(TaskStackBuilder.java:240)
 at android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack(TaskStackBuilder.java:226) 
 at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService.getContentIntent(VideoCastNotificationService.java:492) 
 at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService.build(VideoCastNotificationService.java:329) 
 at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService$2.onPostExecute(VideoCastNotificationService.java:233) 
 at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService$2.onPostExecute(VideoCastNotificationService.java:227) 
 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636) 
 at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177) 
 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Here's how I'm initializing the VCM in my applicaiton:

```
VideoCastManager.initialize(this,
 new CastConfiguration.Builder(BuildConfig.CAST_APP_ID).enableNotification()
 .enableLockScreen()
 .enableWifiReconnection()
 .enableCaptionManagement()
 .enableDebug()
 .addNotificationAction(CastConfiguration.NOTIFICATION_ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE, true)
 .build());
```

Comment: Do you use ProGuard?

Comment: No, I have `minifyEnabled false` for this build as well

Comment: That takes care of the trivial solution then... no idea yet, i'll do some research.

Comment: Have you set any TargetActivity when you initialized the CCL?

Comment: Have you found any solution?